# How to run a bash script in java-ee web application?

Tags: linux, bash, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a web application writen in jsp/servlets & tomcat 7.It will run on linux systems.

I want to run a bash script with root privilages(`gksudo ./myScript.sh`).
My script is under /web directory.(`/web/myScript.sh`).
How can i do that??

I have seen some examples, i managed to run bash shell command(like `ls`), but didn't managed to execute the script!! How i can set as working directory the `/web/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following method to figure out how to get the path to your script:

- [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

To execute a script, you can use the [Runtime class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) like this:

```
String[] commandArray = {
    "/bin/bash",
    "-c",
    "my_script.sh"
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);
```

I've never tried running a script using sudo (or gksudo), so you'll have to play around with that.

Hopefully you can just add it to the array before the script name.

Comment: You probably want /bin/bash, and no `-c`

Comment: Which shell you use is up to you.  Any shell should work (as long as it's the same shell the script is written in). I'll change it to bash to match the tags.  For me `-c` was required after much trial and error.  The OP will probably have to try a few things and see what works.